# How to distribute train set uniformly

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am having the below follow directory structure

```
data/
    train/
        Cat 1/ ### 5000 pictures
            dog001.jpg

            ...
        cat 2/ ### 3000 pictures
            cat001.jpg

       Cat 3/ ### 50000 pictures
            Unicorn.jpg

            ...
        Cat 4/ ### 10000 pictures
            Angels.jpg
```

I am using the following below code load my images

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# automagically retrieve images and their classes for train and validation sets
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="categorical")
```

Since my data is not uniformly distributed so my model does not fit good, it become bias towards `Cat 3` , so how i load a train data that is uniform all the four category ?

Answer (score 0):

you have two approaches:

1. remove some data from `cat3` so the data can be uniform shuffled
2. add data to the other classes

1 is pretty straight forward, to add data you duplicate data from other less frequent classes or, a much better approach is to generate new data from existing

by manipulating the images, you can set one line/col as blank, you can rotate the image or shift it, I used smth like this to achieve those effects one a 28x28 images

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import rotate, shift

def rand_jitter(temp, prob=0.5):
    np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility
    if np.random.random() > prob:
        temp[np.random.randint(0,28,1), :] = 0
    if np.random.random() > prob:
        temp[:, np.random.randint(0,28,1)] = 0
    if np.random.random() > prob:
        temp = shift(temp, shift=(np.random.randint(-3,4,2)))
    if np.random.random() > prob:
        temp = rotate(temp, angle = np.random.randint(-20,21,1), reshape=False)
    return temp
```

by this you can train your network with more data and also generalised it and make its prediction most robust

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove any of your data points, and you should keep as many data points as possible.

To do so, you need to add some code to the existing keras image data generator, but it should be simple. The general idea here is to provide a custom sampling function that uniformly samples a training data point according to the target class, and you can do this in 3 steps:

1. build a dictionary `LUT`={'class-1' : [class-1 files], 'class-2' : [class-2 files], ..., 'class-k': [class-k files]}
2. pick one key in `LUT` in a uniformly random way
3. pick one file in `LUT[key]` in a uniformly random way